# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 How to use jQuery calout plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I want to use jQuery Callout plugin is http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/callout
to customize the display of validation errors.
I put the reference on the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.callout.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Than I set it up like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".field-validation-valid").callout();
    });
</script>

<style>
.callout 
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #7992B0;
    background-color: #8AA9B7;
}
</style>
```

But looks like i set it up wrong, because the displaying behavior of error messages still the same.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Net panel and confirm your page is correctly loading the `~/Scripts/jquery.callout.min.js` file.

If it is, next check the Console tab to see whether it's throwing any JavaScript errors.